# jQuery input mask bundle usuage with the require js || ver : 3.60

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I have been using the jquery inputmask for long time, by updating the to the latest versions

Recently the author released the latest version 3.60, which is amd

> ```
> (function (factory) {
>     if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
>         define("jquery.inputmask", ['jquery'], factory);
>     } else {
>         factory(jQuery);
>     }
> }(function ($) {
>     if ($.fn.inputmask === undefined) {
> ```

When i included the defined the path, in the require definition, it throwing error that

jquery.inputmask is undefined. If any one have used the latest version, know how to use the bundle amd file, please help

**github raw file url**
https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#usage

Look in this section.

```html
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="inputmask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.inputmask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

and add this to re

paths: {
  ...
  "dependencyLib": "../dist/inputmask/dependencyLib",
  "inputmask": "../dist/inputmask/inputmask",
  ...
}

for mee this looks like this

paths: {
 inputmask      : 'jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask',
 dependencyLib             : 'jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask//dependencyLib',
 jQueryInputmask     : 'jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/jquery.inputmask',
}
```